# TSV with Excel clipping off seconds when I save

Tags: excel, datetime, csv

I am trying to edit a TSV file in excel.  When I simply open it and then ctrl-s to save it, I notice when I open it in a text editor that the seconds has been clipped off.  Before opening the file I have: `08/15/2015 18:26:07` but after I have `8/15/15 18:26`.  It's okay that it is clipping off the preceding zeros, but I need the seconds to remain intact for my program.

Any suggestions/ideas?  I'd prefer to use excel if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to adjust the default date/time format in your Excel format settings before saving. To change the date/time format, goto menu Format, Cell, Time and pick one that has seconds. If none meet your needs, try the custom format and then type this format:

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

Comment: I haven't checked this solution out, but I managed to figure it out.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this specifically when dealing with TSV files.  When you open the file and go through the 'text wizard' steps, on the third step, you need to go through each column and tell it to format it as text, rather than as general, which is the default (and lets excel guess what format everything should be).

Comment: This only works at the time of parsing a file. But to avoid truncation in other circumstances and to keep the data types accurate (not confuse date with text), the format method as shown in another answer above is a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean.